# Missing value replacement based on class

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, missing-data

I've been reading an article on Random Forests, and in missing value replacement section (https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#missing1) they say:

> If the mth variable is not categorical, the method computes the median of all values of this variable in class j, then it uses this value to replace all missing values of the mth variable in class j.

Wouldn't that undermine the entire process? If most values in some column are missing, then after this procedure the new values could be used to easily identify the class, and the resulting classifier would be useless. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The resulting classifier is not necessarily useless, it depends on the characteristics of the 'missingness' (the event that a feature value is missing). If its distribution is identical between train and test set (which is a prevailing implicit assumption in ML), it is doing the right thing. However it is indeed problematic if there is a discrepancy, e.g., if missing values are an artifact of the way the training data was generated and mostly associated with one class, while at test time feature values are always fully known. In this case, imputation might lead to incorrect conclusions, especially if the number of missing values is large.